# Why my gradle project always downloading 200MB data from Internet?

Tags: spring, gradle

I am learning basic Spring by following this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). 
I run this command to clone the demo basic project:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git
```

Then I use intelliJ to import the cloned Gradle project. 
However, it always downloading things from Internet, and sometime pop up alert says xxx is not found.

[image]

My question is what is it doing exactly? who and where I tell the code to download things?

It is really confusing to me because I couldn't figure out what is going on.

Comment: There's some android studio / gradle bugs that seems to make it download these dependencies each load instead of remembering them over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project uses gradle to build the application, and the `build.gradle` file is telling gradle that this project needs some dependent libraries to run.

If you look in the build.gradle file, you will find these lines, which are pulling libraries from a [central artifact repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) ([Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in this case).

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

These libraries are [dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) and are necessary for this project to function, and so they must be downloaded.  With that said, it should only need to download them once, after which they should be kept in the gradle artifact cache.